# Indexing html with Sphinx without complex scripts

Tags: html, sphinx

As far as I know the sphinx search engine can index html, but it doesn't have any in-built drivers like it does for sql-data.  That means we have to parse and prepare html content ourselves.

Does anyone know of any drivers or third party add-ons  make sphinx index html automatically?

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have a database of the .html filenames, can use

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-file-field

to index them, sphinx will load each individiaul file in turn and index the contents.

Combine with 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-html-strip

Comment: Sorry. Is there any way to get the content of a certain tag (i.e. "title", "h1") and to put this in a separate index field using an sql_file_field or another Sphinx functionality?

Comment: It has zones feature to deal with that http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-zones which enables the special ZONE limit operator

Comment: One more question. In some cases I have matches with keywords http://joxi.ru/joGIU_3JTJA0VFTn9Hk and everything works great, but in other cases there are no matches. I do have hits   http://joxi.ru/I4KIU_3JTJADVOh9kwo and I'm absolutely sure these words contain keywords.

Comment: The 'words' data, is raw, the number of matches in the whole index, regardless of ANY other filters. Whereas the actual matches (and total_found) honour all the particular filters and the whole text query. ... so suspect even though one of the words match, the whole query doesnt.